# Unable to retrieve .html files from HTTP web server

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

When I run below python script and try to do a GET request for a .html file via safari, I get the content in raw format i.e. along with the HTML tags. How do I retrieve html pages and also if I do a GET for images it says the file is damaged.

```
from socket import *    
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)     #create a socket

serverPort = 7000  
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))  
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:    

    print 'Ready to serve . . .'
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()  #create socket for client
    try:
        message =connectionSocket.recv(1024)   #receive message from client
        print message
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata =f.read()
        #Send HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.x 200 OK\n')
        #Send contents of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close()
        print 'File Received'
    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send('\n404 File Not Found\n')
        connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: Based on what you described, you ARE getting them.  What do you REALLY want to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a web server that fetches html pages. But above code only gives me the html page in its raw format (with the tags). So, when I do GET, e.g. 127.0.0.1:7000/test.html I need the test.html to be displayed.

Comment: Okay, the word you are looking for there is 'rendered'.

Comment: Yes, rendered; my bad. I tried with the below solution as well but I keep getting the same result. I even need to render images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the client that you are sending HTML back.  Before sending the data add:

```
connectionSocket.send("Content-type: text/html\r\n")
```

Also, you may be seeing the HTTP response header you're sending back as well, right?  If so, that's because you have a leading `\n` which terminates the headers and makes the rest of the body that gets sent back, so change that line to

```
connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\n')
```

and make sure you put a blank line when you are done with all the headers, and also that end of line in HTTP should be `\r\n` not just `\n` though I wouldn't be surprised if browsers handled it with just `\n`

Comment: Yes, I am seeing the response header as well. I made the following changes, but still getting the same result
        `connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.x 200 OK\r\n"
            "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
            "\r\n")`
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I just eliminated the part where I specified the header and it did the trick. Not sure why earlier solution didn't work though.

Comment: I'm not sure why things would not work with the `Content-type` header, but the original version may have had the issue with the `\n` before the HTTP status line.  Anyway, glad to hear things are working for you now.  One thing that could be wrong with the header, I gave you the wrong capitalization, it should be `Content-Type`

Comment: I tried with the correct capitalization, still the same. But I also just noticed, that when I try to access any particular file I can access it but when I hit the root directory I get 404 page not found instead of getting the directory listing.